# ChromeDriver with Selenium and Python - Automatically allow microphone use

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing and automation for a WebRTC client that requires a microphone stream to be allowed on Chrome

Since i'm using chromedriver to perform all the actions, i'm looking for a way to allow the microphone automatically when starting the script

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the use-fake-device-for-media-stream and use-fake-ui-for-media-stream command line flags. See [here](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/test/selenium-lib.js#L73-L79) for what the adapter.js project uses for automated tests. The python bits should be similar to the JS bits shown there hopefully.